# My PC does not respond to power on switch immediately though USB ports seem to receive power

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply, power

I have gotten a PC assembled for my home use.

Since a few months, I am experiencing a strange issue while powering the PC on.

When I switch on the wall button of the machine (in which the power cable of my CPU is plugged in), I can see that the motherboard is powered up because the LED on my external hard drive which is connected to one of the onboard USB ports comes on instantly.

However, when I press the Power On button on the CPU, there is no response. No fans, no LEDs, **nothing**.

**Now comes the puzzling part.**

If I press the Power On button on CPU for more than 5 seconds my machine remains dead for a couple of minutes and then *voila*!, it powers on!!!. Some times, the PC powers on instantly and some times it takes about a minute or two.

Can somebody please explain why such a simple task as powering of my PC is giving me such erratic results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing on the power button like that may serve to bleed excess charge from
your motherboard, and that charge is what is blocking the boot.

I would suggest to check if the plug used to connect to the mains is
correctly earthed, then check the Power Supply Unit (PSU).
You could also visually inspect the capacitors on the motherboard,
to see if one looks to be bloated or otherwise damaged.
The CMOS battery is also a possibility.

If you cannot find anything, or don't have the tools for it,
a computer repair-shop may be able to identify the problem and fix it.

Comment: Everything appears OK inside the cabinet. So repair-shop it is. Thanks for the advice.